# Ansible playbook : loop in variable

Tags: ansible

I want to create a loop that checks if a file exists at a specific location.

Here is my ansible playbook:

```
- name: Launch purge script
  hosts: roi-asb-01p
  vars_files:
    - instance_test.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Check if file test.php exists
      stat:
        path: "/home/alekso/instance_test/prod/{{ instance_all }}/test.php"
      register: result
        #  loop: "{{ instance_all }}"
    - name : DEBUG FILE EXISTS
      debug:
        msg: "The file test.php exist"
      when: result.stat.exists
      loop: "{{ instance_all }}"
    - name: DEBUG FILE NOT EXISTS
      debug:
        msg: "The file test.php doesn't exist"
      when: not result.stat.exists
      loop: "{{ instance_all }}"
```

the problem is that for the path, it includes each instance of my "instance_all" variable in my instance_test.yml file so it detects that no file exists because the path is not good

The path suddenly looks like this: `/home/test/instance_test/prod/[one, two, tree]/test.php` instead of `/home/test/instance_test/prod/one/test.php` etc...

And here is my file with my different variables :

```
instance_all:
  - one
  - two
  - tree

instance_1:
  - test1

instance_2:
  - test2
```

Here is the command output :

```
test@srv-test-1:~/ansible/test$ ansible-playbook -i inventaire.ini launch-purge-script-test.yml
[WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use -vvvv to see details
[WARNING]: An error occurred while calling ansible.utils.display.initialize_locale (unsupported locale setting). This may result in incorrectly calculated text widths
that can cause Display to print incorrect line lengths

PLAY [Launch purge script] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [roi-asb-01p]

TASK [Check if file test.php exists] *************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [roi-asb-01p]

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [roi-asb-01p] => (item=one) 
skipping: [roi-asb-01p] => (item=two) 
skipping: [roi-asb-01p] => (item=tree) 
skipping: [roi-asb-01p]

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [roi-asb-01p] => (item=one) => {
    "msg": "The file test.php doesn't exist"
}
ok: [roi-asb-01p] => (item=two) => {
    "msg": "The file test.php doesn't exist"
}
ok: [roi-asb-01p] => (item=tree) => {
    "msg": "The file test.php doesn't exist"
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
roi-asb-01p                : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Thanks for help

Comment: This is just a "typo". Instead of using `{{ instance_all }}` within your `loop`, you need to use `{{ item }}` or define your own loop variable. Please have a look into [Iterating over a simple list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-a-simple-list). Furthermore it is recommended to not post pictures into your question, but copy and paste the text only and format it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Ok I will think about it for my next questions

Comment: Would it be possible to edit already this question to make it easier readable and reproducible?

Comment: Ok I have change my question

Answer (score 1):

The variable `instance_all` contains all elements that you want to loop over. But you need one single elemet in each iteration. This is contained in the loop_var (by default its name is `item`). This would do it in your case:

```
path: /home/test/instance_test/prod/{{ item }}/test.php
```

Of course, you should also remove the comment symbol from the line with `# loop:`.

Comment: @Azrod, regarding "_but the problem is always present_", the error message has changed from `/home/test/instance_test/prod/[one, two, tree]/test.php` to `'item' is undefined`. This is because you've probably left the line `# loop: {{ instance_all }}` unchanged and therefore commented out. It is also recommend to not post such errors as comment.

Comment: Ok sorry, I didn't know, I don't know the good practice here yet, I deleted the comment.
However after modifying the part you spoke to me about, I still find an error, I tried all possible types of configuration by modifying the location of the loop module but nothing worked, I still have an error.

Comment: @Azrod, regarding "_I still have an error_", the error message change from `'item' is undefined` to no error message, but `skipping` the hosts. There is additionally a warning about your inventory file `Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced` and `An error occurred while calling ansible.utils.display.initialize_locale`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate this error further and look at `ansible.utils.display.initialize_locale`

I will come back to you after my additional research